# How to make provisioning profile for iphone app?

Tags: iphone

Hi everyone i would like to know that how to make the provisioning profile for iphone app.I want to test my app on the device and i don't know what i need to do to make that possible to test the app.Please anyone can help me in the steps for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test on a device(rather than just in the iPhone simulator), you need to register with Apple to be iOS developer. It costs 100 dollars a year:
http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: Yes i know that ,we have already registered.I i just wanted to know how to test the app then on iphone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to folow the instructions.
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

In the Provisioning Portal, in the Home section there is a Wizard
to learn how to do what you are looking for.

"Get your application on an iOS with the Development Provisioning Assistant"